# C# (Unity 4.3) Cannot implicitly convert type `ShotScript[]' to `ShotScript'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**Thanks all! The issue was I was using GetComponents rather than GetComponent, thanks!**

I am fairly new to programming and I am trying to make a 2D game in Unity. I have found a tutorial online which is really good, up until a point (Tut can be found here http://pixelnest.io/tutorials/2d-game-unity/shooting-1/). I've come across an error and can't figure out why. The error occurs when I try and use another script inside my current script (if that makes sense to anyone). The two scripts in question have the name ShotScript and HealthScript and they are below

ShotScript:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ShotScript : MonoBehaviour {


public int damage = 1;

public bool isEnemyShot = false;

void Start () {

    Destroy (gameObject, 20);
}



}
```

HealthScript:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour {


public int hp = 2;

public bool isEnemy = true;

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D Collider) {

        ShotScript shot = collider.gameObject.GetComponents<ShotScript>();
            if (shot != null) {
                    if (shot.isEnemyShot != isEnemy) {
                            hp -= shot.damage;
                            Destroy (shot.gameObject);

                            if (hp <= 0) {
                                    Destroy(gameObject);
                            }
                    }
            }
    }


}
```

The error I get is:
"Assets/Scripts/HealthScript.cs(13,36): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type      `ShotScript[]' to`ShotScript'"

I'm rather stuck and so if anyone could point me in the right direction, that'll be great =)

P.S I'm new to this asking questions thing, so if you need any extra info, I'll do my best to provide it

Comment: It means what it says. I assume the problem is on the line `ShotScript shot = collider.gameObject.GetComponents<ShotScript>();` Does the `GetComponents` method return an array?

Comment: Yes, I was supposed to type GetComponent =P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling [`GetComponents`](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponents.html) (notice the plural) which returns an array (that is `ShotScript[]`) of all matching components of the type on that particular `GameObject`.

So this is attempting to assign a `ShotScript[]` array into a single `ShotScript` instance which is not possible.

If you wanted to retrieve only one `ShotScript` (because you intend to have only 1 on an object), use the [`GetComponent`](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html) (notice the singular) method instead which will return only one instance or `null` if none are assigned.

So change the one line to this:

```
ShotScript shot = collider.gameObject.GetComponent<ShotScript>();
```

---

If your intent was to handle many `ShotScript` instances/components on the same `GameObject`, use the fix/code supplied in [Jon Skeet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21208116/1269654).

Answer (score 3):

Well this is the problem:

```
ShotScript shot = collider.gameObject.GetComponents<ShotScript>();
```

It sounds like `GetComponents<ShotScript>` is returning an *array* of `ShotScript` references, i.e. its return type is `ShotScript`.

Do you want to take the same action for each `ShotScript`? If so, you probably want to just use a `foreach` loop... although you probably only want to check for the `hp` going negative at the end. I would expect you to be able to remove the check for nullity, too, assuming that `GetComponents` will just return an empty array if there aren't any such components:

```
ShotScript[] shots = collider.gameObject.GetComponents<ShotScript>();
foreach (ShotScript shot in shots)
{
    if (shot.isEnemyShot != isEnemy)
    {
        hp -= shot.damage;
        Destroy(shot.gameObject);
    }
}
if (hp <= 0)
{
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

(I've reformatted that to be rather more conventional C#, but of course you can use whatever indentation you want.)

Answer (score 0):

The error message says that line 13 is in error:

```
ShotScript shot = collider.gameObject.GetComponents<ShotScript>();
```

It looks like the `GetComponents` method is returning an array `ShotScript[]`, but you're trying to implicity cast it to just a single `ShotScript` instance.  Try:

```
ShotScript[] shots = collider.gameObject.GetComponents<ShotScript>();
```